# Can dart pass array or dictionary object to native extension?

Tags: dart

Can I pass array or dictionary object from dart to native extension by Dart_Handle? If it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the dictionary object but you can do it with array/list. You can see here that the Dart_CObject struct can be of the type Dart_CObject_kArray which you can get with call as_array on the Dart_Object:

```cpp
struct {
  intptr_t length;
  struct _Dart_CObject** values;
} as_array;
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/include/dart_native_api.h#L68

You can then access the values inside the list as normal array (e.g. get first element where "message" are of the type Dart_CObject*):

```cpp
Dart_CObject* param0 = message->value.as_array.values[0];
```

I have made a project where I uses lists as argument to native code. The relevant part for you can be found here:

https://github.com/julemand101/lirc_client/blob/master/lib/src/lirc_extension.cc#L126